# Is __DATASETS__ syntax supported just like __TABLES__?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to view all existing datasets in a project and properties for those datasets just like I can view when using __TABLES__.  Is there an equivalent syntax for querying all datasets?  The following doesn't work for me:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_QUERY([gdelt-bq:__DATASETS__], 'true') 
LIMIT 1000
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM [gdelt-bq:__DATASETS__.__TABLES__] 
LIMIT 1000
```

but the following will give me information on all tables in a given dataset.  Is there a query that can be run to get a list of all datasets in a project?

```
SELECT *
FROM [gdelt-bq:extra.__TABLES__] 
LIMIT 1000
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know - unfortunately, there is no `__DATASETS__` equivalent of `__TABLES__` - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#meta-tables

Still, you can use respective [Datasets: list API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/datasets/list) or list datasets using respective [bq ls](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool#listdatasets)